# Issue Importing CineForm to Premiere CS6

Tags: premiere

I installed the GoPro CineForm codec recently and used VDub to create a CineForm AVI file. Works fine in MPCHC, VDub, etc.
It won't import into Premiere Pro CS6 though. I get an error about an unsupported or damaged file.
When exporting, "CineForm AVI" and "CineForm MOV" are both options, and I can export timelines as CineForm AVI that, again, works fine in MPCHC and VDub but won't import into Premiere.
For a while I was getting this error when opening AME, but it stopped after a reboot:

Monitor: PProHeadless.exe - System Error

The program can't start because CFHDDecoder64.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

OK

I'm still getting this error when I open After Effects:

After Effects warning: The following plugins have failed to load.  Please reinstall these plugins:
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Common\Plug-ins\CS6\MediaCore\CineForm\CFHD_AVI_Importer.prm
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Common\Plug-ins\CS6\MediaCore\CineForm\CFHD_MOV_Importer.prm

OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just browsing around C:/, and stumbled across CFHDDecoder.dll and CFHDDecoder64.dll in C:/Program Files (x86)/CineForm/Tools. Copied them to C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Premiere Pro CS6, and the file now imports successfully.